# How following c program works?

Tags: c

This is the program

```
void message();
int main() {
    message();
    printf("Cry,and stop the monotony");
    return 0;
}
void message() {
    printf("smile and see");
}
```

In this program `message` function is called in `main()` but it is defined after function main so if the program execution begins from top side then it should generate error but it still works?how? can someone explain me?
second one can I write this program like this:

```
void message() {
     printf("smile and see");
}
int main() {
    message();
    printf("Cry,and stop the monotony");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please edit the post to make it readable

Comment: You need to learn the basics of how an executable is generated from source code, starting with the functions of a compiler and a linker.

Comment: Program execution doesn't "begin from top side". The entry point is your `main()` function. It's actually more complicated than that but it's close enough for a beginner's understanding.

Comment: You Should Read about functions and compiler working process in c++.

Answer (score 4):

It can be compiled because the declaration

```
void message();
```

tells to the compiler that such a function exists and is defined somewhere. It is so called *forward declaration*. The compiler then finds it after main function.

Forward declaration is used sometimes to declare that some entity exists somewhere and is defined but not yet, here you state just that it exists and you would like to use it. In case of class forward declaration you can use a pointer and reference to class objects without including class definition. For example

file.h

```
class Something;
// not included but I can use a pointer or reference
// as long as I don't call methods on it

void function( Something const& s);
```

file.cpp

```
#include "Something.h" // now it is needed because I will call a function on s
#include "file.h"

void function( Something const& s) {
    s.sing();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first line

```
void message();
```

is a forward declaration. That tells the compiler that an implementation of that function exists and follows.

Answer (score 1):

```
void message(); // This is the function declaration 

int main(){

message(); // Calls message()
printf("Cry,and stop the monotomy"); // Prints this phrase

return 0;

}

void message(){ // This is the function definition

   printf("smile and see");

}
```

That's all there is to this example.

NO this is unconventional:

```
void message() {

 printf("smile and see");

}

int main(){

message();

printf("Cry,and stopthemonotomy");

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your First Code

```
void message();
int main() {
    message();
    printf("Cry,and stop the monotomy");
    return 0;
}
void message() {
    printf("smile and see");
}
```

The c++ compiler works from Top to Bottom Approach so it will first find the statement
`void Message();` as this is a declaration of function so it treat it as a Forward Declaration.
and Search for the definition in remaining code.

And About the Second Code Block:

Compiler itself find the definition  of function at the first line `void message(){...}`
So it treat as a declaration and Definition.